# Relationship field problem: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

My code is:

```
<?php 
$posts = get_field('designer'); 
if ( $posts ): ?>
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): ?>
<?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
<div class="design">
    <h4><?php _e("[:tr]Tasarım[:][:en]Design[:]","qtranslate-x"); ?></h4>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
    </a>
    <?php if( get_field('profile_image') ): ?>
         <img src="<?php the_field('profile_image'); ?>" width="200" class="img-responsive">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <p>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </p>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This results in this error message:

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 
in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/addo/wp-includes/query.php 
on line 3920
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the code that triggers the error? Line `3920` in `wp-includes/query.php` is in `rewind_posts()`, and the error is happening because `post_count` is greater than `0`, but `$wp_query->posts` isn't an array... which is odd to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setup_postdata()`requires a post object such what you would get by using the `global $post`. You are using a custom field, presumably from ACF, and calling it $post. The problem is that it is not an object.

You can use the field `$designer` in a customised post loop like so:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 

        $designer = get_field('designer'); 

        if($designer){
           the_field('designer');
        }
    } 
}
```

Another way to solve this might be to make sure the designer custom field returns a post object. To see the value of `get_field('designer')` you can do something like:

```
$designer = get_field('designer');
var_dump($designer);
```

A post object will contain all the relevant information (title, content, etc.).

Comment: You're very welcome :)